# Google places not working in ionic modal screen

Tags: modal-dialog, ionic-framework, google-places-api

i am trying to use google places in ionic modal but not able to select the place.

the main screen it's working fine. i could able to search and select a location. 
but when you open modal window by clicking the "Google Place" button, i am not able to select the address in the modal window. i am not getting the lat and long in modal window.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

see my plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/e01DFWDvicLJa6Ouluz7?p=preview1

here is my html:

```
<ion-content>
    <div>
      <div>Google Places Autocomplte integration in Angular</div>
      <div>To Test, start typing the name of any Indian city</div>
      <div>selection is: {{chosenPlace}}</div>
      <div>
        <input ng-model="chosenPlace" details="chosenPlaceDetails" googleplace/>
      </div>

      <div>lat: {{chosenPlaceDetails.geometry.location.lat()}}</div>
      <div>lang: {{chosenPlaceDetails.geometry.location.lng()}}</div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div> -->
  </ion-content>
```

modal html:

```
<div class="modal">
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Choose </h1>
    <a ng-click="closeGooglePlaceModal()()" class="button button-icon icon ion-close"></a>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="item" ng-click="clickLocationItem(item.ID)" ng-repeat="item in locations" ng-bind-html="item.Nome"></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
      <div>Google Places Autocomplte integration in Angular</div>
      <div>To Test, start typing the name of any Indian city</div>
      <div>selection is: {{chosenPlace1}}</div>
      <div>details object is Lattitude: {{chosenPlaceDetails1.geometry.location.lat()}}</div>

      <div>
        <input ng-model="chosenPlace1" details="chosenPlaceDetails1" googleplace/>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})


/*https://github.com/jvandemo/angularjs-google-maps*/
.directive('googleplace', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      details: '=?'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {

      //$scope.gPlace;

      console.log("....1");
    },

    link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
      var options = {
        types: [],
        componentRestrictions: {}
      };
      scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);

      google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {

        console.log("....2");
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.details = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
          console.log(scope.details.geometry.location.lat());
          model.$setViewValue(element.val());
        });
      });
    }
  };
})


.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPlatform, $ionicModal) {

  $scope.gPlace;

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('googleplace.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modalGooglePlace = modal;

    // $scope.modal.show();
  });

  $scope.openGooglePlace = function() {

    /*prepare modal*/

    $scope.modalGooglePlace.show();


  }

  $scope.closeGooglePlaceModal = function() {

    $scope.modalGooglePlace.hide();

  }

});
```

regards,

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

After hours of web-research I started searching a solution by myself and finally found it.

Ionic adds a "pointer-events: none" css-style when opening a modal view.
This suppresses all cursor events, such as hover, etc. so we cant get the Places-Ites-Hover-Event.

Just add the "pointer-events: auto;" style to the .pac-container class.

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Great tip. Last two hours am searching for this. Thanks!.